# simplify a log expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I met a problem, I don't know if this term can be simplified properly?

$$e^{ (\ln ax^{b})^{c}}$$

since the ln term with power of c is hard to cope with, thanks for any help!

Comment: your term $\ln ax^b$ isn't clear for me, what is what you mean?

Comment: I mean,a and b are const, and it is equal to b*\ ln (a*x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $e^{\ln(ax^b)*\ln(ax^b)^{c-1}} = (ax^b)^{(\ln(ax^b))^{c-1}}$  It doesn't simplify any more than that unfortunately.

Comment: And it is doubtful whether that is even a simplification, because it replaces the nice constant $e$ by something that involves variables, without making anything _else_ simpler.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. That double (?) exponent is just not nice to tangle with.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's generally nothing productive to do here, unless you know that $c$ is some particular nice number such that $0$ or $1$ ...

It may be useful to rewrite the expression in parentheses to $\ln a + b\ln x$, but whether that is actually progress depends on what you eventual goal is.

Comment: actually, c might be 0.5.but it stills sounds hard to solve.Is it possible to solve when c = 0.5?

Comment: @KennyYang: What does "solve" mean to you here?

Comment: maybe I can simplify this term into a much clean form?

Answer (score 0):

You can't simplify it much. You can rewrite it as $e^{{(\ln ax^b)}^{c-1}(\ln ax^b)}$ and then as $(\ln ax^b)^{{(\ln ax^b)}^{c-1}}$ but that's pretty much all you can do here.